# Signals not modified in some cases

Tags: case, verilog

Here is an simplified example of case in sequential logic

```
always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
if (!rst_n) begin
  enable <= 1'b0;
  t_A    <= 1'b0;
  t_B    <= 1'b0;
  t_C    <= 1'b0;
end
else begin
  case (nxt_state)
  IDLE: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
    t_A    <= 1'b0;
    t_B    <= 1'b0;
    t_C    <= 1'b0;
  end
  LOAD: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
    t_A    <= A;
    t_B    <= B;
    t_C    <= C;
  end
  BUSY: begin
    enable <= 1'b1;
  end
  DONE: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
  end
  default: begin
    enable <= enable;
    t_A    <= t_A;
    t_B    <= t_B;
    t_C    <= t_C;
  end
  endcase
end
```

Signals t_* will only load new value while nxt_state is "LOAD". If I don't list signals t_* in case "BUSY" and "DONE, will they keep their values?

I've tried add some code before case clause as below, but it shows some warning while running linting tool

```
always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
if (!rst_n) begin
  enable <= 1'b0;
  t_A    <= 1'b0;
  t_B    <= 1'b0;
  t_C    <= 1'b0;
end
else begin

  enable <= enable;
  t_A    <= t_A;
  t_B    <= t_B;
  t_C    <= t_C;    

  case (nxt_state)
  IDLE: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
    t_A    <= 1'b0;
    t_B    <= 1'b0;
    t_C    <= 1'b0;
  end
  LOAD: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
    t_A    <= A;
    t_B    <= B;
    t_C    <= C;
  end
  BUSY: begin
    enable <= 1'b1;
  end
  DONE: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
  end
  default: begin
    enable <= enable;
    t_A    <= t_A;
    t_B    <= t_B;
    t_C    <= t_C;
  end
  endcase
end
```

How can I fix it to keep the code simple and clear?

Answer (score 0):

You've already stated to keep previous value in default option. That is more than enough. Besides, if a signal gets assigned value in one "if" block but didn't appears in its else counter part, the synthesizer normally would synthesize a latch to retain its previous value.

Answer (score 0):

what you really do here is creating a bunch of flops to keep your state machine going. The definition of a flop is that it will keep the value on the output till the next edge of a clock (or rst, or whatever). So, here is a simplistic model of a flop:

```
reg q;
always @(posedge clk)
    q <= d;
```

In the above case, `q` will be stable between clock edges, meaning that its value will be kept in the register.

something more compilcated with an enable signal:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    if (en)
        q <= d;
```

In the above the value of `q` will be stable between clock edges and will only change at clk edge if `en` is high. in all other cases it will keep the value.

So, in your case first of all you do **not** need the `default` clause. the values will be stable without it.

if you do not list the signals in BUSY and DONE, the values will not change from the previous state. So, your initial variant was correct, except that no default is needed there.

```
always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
if (!rst_n) begin
  enable <= 1'b0;
  t_A    <= 1'b0;
  t_B    <= 1'b0;
  t_C    <= 1'b0;
end
else begin
  case (nxt_state)
  IDLE: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
    t_A    <= 1'b0;
    t_B    <= 1'b0;
    t_C    <= 1'b0;
  end
  LOAD: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
    t_A    <= A;
    t_B    <= B;
    t_C    <= C;
  end
  BUSY: begin
    enable <= 1'b1;
  end
  DONE: begin
    enable <= 1'b0;
  end
  endcase
end
```

One thing i noticed is that you do not update the `next_state` here. you should figure out how to do it.